# Group Unique ID

Tags: social-networking, stata

In stata if I have a list if groups:
    XYZ
    ABC
    ABC
    BCH
    JSA
    BCH
    XYZ
How I get each group to have a unique ID in a second column after sorting, for example:

```
ABC 1
BCH 2
JSA 3
XYZ 4
```

Comment: No need for tags in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `sort`, then `group()`, which is part of `egen`.

```
sysuse auto,clear
sort make
egen make_gp = group(make)
```

This yields:

```
. list make make_gp in 1/5

     +-------------------------+
     | make            make_gp |
     |-------------------------|
  1. | AMC Concord           1 |
  2. | AMC Pacer             2 |
  3. | AMC Spirit            3 |
  4. | Buick Century         7 |
  5. | Buick Electra         8 |
     +-------------------------+
```